# How to retrieve the elapsed time took in execution of an .exe file or opening a .pdf file. The mentioned code couldn't help out

Tags: python-3.x, performance-testing, desktop-application, execution-time

'''Here I have tried following code in python 3.7, but it is not fetching the elapsed time took to open the pdf file'''

```
start = timeit()
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files\AcroRD32.exe')
end = timeit()
elapsed_time = end - start
```

Comment: Please provide the value of `elapsed_time` that you get and what would be your expected result.

Comment: start time: 0.037696500000002686
end time: 0.043419000000000096
elapsed_time: 0:00:00.005722        it should be more than this given elapsed time because I received this calculation before my pdf screen appeared. That is why I am suspecting.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from time import time 
start = time() 
# ... do something 
time_used = round(time() - start)
# this is in seconds, convert if you need 
time_str = f'{time_used//3600}:{str((time_used%3600)//60):0>2}:{str(time_used%60):0>2}'
print(time_str)
```

Comment: Thanks for response but it is not making any difference with my code provided. Even though timeit() is more efficient I am still not able to find the elapsed time to open the .pdf file.

Comment: that's interesting, you tried my code and still no result? Because there is literally a script running on my screen right now using the exact same code and it works

Comment: Just for clarification I applied the same code to open 3 different desktop applications say .pdf, one note and Cisco client, but what I observed that the elapsed time calculation result appears before the application completely opens. I think it is not observing the application opening time properly.

Comment: that's probably because the script only calculated the time to SIGNAL something to open. Opening application takes time, you'd need something more advance to tell the script to wait for program to load

Comment: In that way it will add the waiting time also

Comment: but he's using subprocess.popen, doesn't that mean the subprocess is responsible for wait time rather than the main process?

Comment: could you please help me how to make the program understand that it has to wait untill the application (.pdf or certain .exe) opens up.

Comment: I think, either use `os.system()` instead of `subprocess` or create an independent process with `Process()` and put the timer within that process, and let the new process print the result.